# Android onClick method for TextSwticher

Tags: android, android-activity, onclicklistener

2Can someone help me with onClick method?
basically i have a array which changes every few seconds. Goal is when "1" displays and if user clicks on screen new activity displays same goes when "2" display and if user click on screen different activity class displays.

```
     public TextSwitcher mSwitcher, mSwitcher1, mSwitcher2;


    String textToShow[] = {
            "1", "2"
    };


 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_layout, container, false);

        mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) v.findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);

        mSwitcher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent n = null;
                switch (){
                case 0:
                    n = new Intent(getActivity(), FragMent1.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    n = new Intent(getActivity(), FragMent2.class);
                    break;
                }
                if(null!=n)
                    startActivity(n);
            }

                //Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Listtube.class);
                //getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);        


        });
```

errors

```
03-23 21:10:09.216: W/dalvikvm(1876): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1b11ba8)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): Process: com.example.actionbartab, PID: 1876
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.actionbartab/com.example.actionbartab.FragMent1}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.actionbartab.FragMent1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.actionbartab.FragMent1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
03-23 21:10:09.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1876):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: And what is the actual problem you are currently having?

Comment: how can i getViewbyID? i have manage to open new activity if user click on screen.. but my goal is that when "1" displays and if user click on it fragment1.class shows and if "2" displays and if user click on it fragment2.class displays. missing item is switch (?) to getvalue of position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `id` of the `View` parameter then use that in your `switch`. Something like

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent n = null;
       int id = v.getId();
       switch (id){
           case R.id.someId:
                n = new Intent(getActivity(), FragMent1.class);
                break;
           case R.id.someOtherId:
                n = new Intent(getActivity(), FragMent2.class);
                break;
        }
```

It sounds like this is what you are looking for. If not, please explain a little better what you want.

**Edit**

I'm not sure that I understand your latest problem but if I do then you can do something like

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent n = null;
       int id = v.getId();
       switch (id){
           case R.id.someId:
           case R.id.someOtherId:
                n = new Intent(getActivity(), FragMent1.class);
                break;
```

Comment: Yes i was looking for "int id = v.getId();" but for some reason its not changing to that particular activity.

Comment: i set first case tobe R.id.textSwitcher and ran into few errors.

Comment: You are trying to start a `Fragment` with `startActivity()`. You should be trying to start the `Activity` which holds that `Fragment`

Comment: great working now, lifesaver. But what if i want to start the activity which holds that fragment?

Comment: I don't understand. Start the `Activity`

Comment: Disregard my previous question, but i got new one. case "R.id.someId" and "R.id.someotherId". I want to use same Id, because i have array which has some amount of images, and it animates at one place, i am assuming for using second Id will change location not only that i'm using mSwitcher.setOnClickListener which is associated which R.id.textSwitcher.

Comment: @Mihir See my edit. I'm not sure I understand but maybe that is what you mean. If not, you may need to post a new question with more clearly stated details. I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for help me out, but here is a new question i hope it has more details to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626305/android-onclick-method-imageswitcher

Answer (score 1):

Fragment and Activity are difference.
Activity.startActivity(Intent) method call new Activity but FragMent1 is not Activity.
so you can't cast FragMent1 class to Activity class.
if FragMent1 inherit Fragment, you should use FragmentManager.

```
Fragment fragment = FragMent1();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

R.id.content is id of one of layout.

---

It just is simple example code. you should write the code depending your application.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    switch ( id ) {
    case R.id.fragment1:
        fragment = new FragMent1();
        args.putString("someKey1", "someValue1");
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        showFragment(fragment);
        break;
    case R.id.fragment2:
        fragment = new FragMent2();
        args.putString("someKey2", "someValue2");
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        showFragment(fragment);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

public void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: great but how will that work dynamically? i will be having 20 string array. would like it to switch between 20 fragment.

Comment: by user some action, if Fragment is changed to other Fragment, you call code above. just you choose fragment you wanted. also if you want to send data to the Fragment, call Fragment.setArguments(Bundle).

Comment: Thanks you for your help but basically my new activity is "public class Listtube extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity implementsView.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener" which is not a fragment. i tried to convert it to fragment but couldn't.

Comment: sorry, I think FragMent1 is Fragment class. 
if FragMent1(Listtube) is Activity, use code of codeMagic above. 
for detail answer, we need more information.