# Android onClick method ImageSwitcher

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

Basically i got one array which has 2 image as if for now but eventually will have more.
Images from array switcher every few seconds. i'm stuck with onClick method. Ultimate goal when user clicks on that image new Activity class opens up.  Each image has its own Activity class so when user clicks on it, it should be directed to that particular class.

I did got some help yesterday

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent n = null;
       int id = v.getId();
       switch (id){
           case R.id.someId:
                n = new Intent(getActivity(), FragMent1.class);
                break;
           case R.id.someOtherId:
                n = new Intent(getActivity(), FragMent2.class);
                break;
        }
```

i can set first case statement to be "R.id.textSwitcher" but second is the problem. Because i want images animates to at one place, new R.id... means new location also new "mSwitcher1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()"

```
public class Animation extends Fragment implements AnimationListener {

    public HomeAnimation(){}
    private static boolean flag = false;
     Animation anim;
     private Handler handler;
     public ImageSwitcher mSwitcher,mSwitcher1;

    int textToShow[] = {R.drawable.dabangg, R.drawable.car };

    int messageCount = textToShow.length;
    int currentIndex = -1;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imgswitch, container, false);
        mSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) v.findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher1);
        mSwitcher.setFactory(mFactory);
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fade_in);

        mSwitcher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent n = null;
                 int id = v.getId();
                // Fragment fragment = null;
                //Bundle args = new Bundle();
                switch (v.getId()){
                case 0:
                    n = new Intent(getActivity(), Fragment1.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(n);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    n = new Intent(getActivity(), Fragment2.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(n);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        // set animation listener
        anim.setAnimationListener(this);
        return v;    
    }

public void updateTextView() {

    int maxIndex = textToShow.length;
    Random random = new Random();
    int generatedIndex = random.nextInt(maxIndex);
    mSwitcher.setImageResource(textToShow[generatedIndex]);
```

}

Here is a what i updated in case if anyone needs it

```
public void updateTextView() {

        int maxIndex = textToShow.length;
        Random random = new Random();
        final int generatedIndex = random.nextInt(maxIndex);
        mSwitcher.setImageResource(textToShow[generatedIndex]);
        mSwitcher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent n = null;

                 switch(generatedIndex){
                 case 0:
                     n = new Intent(getActivity(), Fragment1.class);
                       getActivity().startActivity(n);
                       break;

                 case 1:
                      n = new Intent(getActivity(), Fragment2.class);
                       getActivity().startActivity(n);
                       break;
                 case 2:
                       n = new Intent(getActivity(), Fragment3.class);
                       getActivity().startActivity(n);
                       break;

                }
            }
         });
```

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Comment: Ultimate goal, when user clicks on that image new Activity class opens up. Each image has its own Activity class so when user clicks on it, it should be directed to that particular class.

Comment: Is the problem that the `id` you are getting is the `id` of the `ImageSwitcher ` but you need the actual `Image` that is currently showing? If so, then maybe [getDisplayedChild()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#getDisplayedChild()) is what you want

Comment: codeMagic - i have added my full code to the original question, can you please help me, how can i find out the Id of currently showing image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to test this right now and I'm not completely sure I understand where your problem is but try this and see if it is what you want. I will put comments in the code

```
mSwitcher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent n = null;
             int id = v.getId();
            // Fragment fragment = null;
            //Bundle args = new Bundle();
            switch (v.getId()){
            case 0:
              /* 
                 below should give you the index for the displayed image
                 you can compare this to the ids in your array using the index
              */
               if (v.getDisplayedChild() == 0) { // if 1st image in array do this
                   n = new Intent(getActivity(), Fragment1.class);
                   getActivity().startActivity(n);
               }
               if (v.getDisplayedChild() == 1) { // if 2nd image in array do this
                   n = new Intent(getActivity(), Fragment2.class);
                   getActivity().startActivity(n);
               }
              break;
```

Comment: @Mihir Ok, let me know if this isn't what you are looking for

Comment: Its working now, please take a look at the original question. i have updated some minor stuff. Only thing now i have to worry is that app is keep on crashing because it might be doing lots of work in main thread.

Comment: @Mihir I looked at your original question but I don't see anything that would cause that crash. Maybe you have other code that is looping through doing a lot of operations or something similar?

Comment: i have added my full code to original question. i do have runnables which does the animation. I have noticed in Logcat is that when i clicked on any image and when its about to go to new activity class that's when ~300-500 frames skips and thats when i sees doing lots of work in the main thread. My plan is to convert activity to fragment and see if that would make any difference.

Comment: codeMagic - i found the issue, problem was image size used in array were too much.. everything working now :)